# ACF Как назначить поля для всех типов записи?

Tags: wordpress, acf

Есть необходимость, что б поля плагина добавлялись на любой тип записи в теме WordPress.
[image: ACF]
Как изображено на скриншоте. В данном случаи я хочу подключить поле `Subtitle Text` на page, post, projects(кастомный тип записи), но почему-то не отображаеться. Хотя если указать только один тип записи, допустим - страницы, то отобразиться на каждой странице. Что я делаю не так ? Как поправить ?

Comment: Потому что логика "И". А надо "ИЛИ" (А записи - они в ВП, а не в теме)

Comment: Спасибо, да помогло... оно там ниже выбираеться